# Некорректное создание элементов c указанием класса или id в HTML с помощью Emmet

Tags: html, html5, emmet

Чтоб создать элемент с указанием его класса и/или id я использую Emmet и прописываю, например:

```
.class_name
```

и затем жму Tab. В результате получаю:

```
.<div class="class_nam"></div>
```

или

```
.<class_name></class_name>
```

или элемент не строится вообще. Как видно, перед созданным элементом добавилась ненужная точка, а в имени класса отсутствует последняя буква. Причем при явном задание тега все работает нормально. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка, и как ее исправить?

Comment: какой редактор используется? И какой результат ожидается?

Comment: @Grundy Sublime Text. Ожидаю, что элементы будут строиться без лишних точек и с "необрезанным" именем класса, ну и вообще будут строиться.